# Identifying which button was pressed

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to build a GUI which has a lot of buttons(JButton)/dropdown items (JMenuItem) and when each button containing letters is pressed the associated letter is being added to a label.

I'm having trouble identifying which button was pressed.Can you please give me a tip on how to do this?

### Code:

```
 private void dodajCrko(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           
    jlStatus.setText(jlStatus.getText() + evt.getSource()/* what to add here?*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the getActionCommand() method:

```
private void dodajCrko(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           
    jlStatus.setText(jlStatus.getText() + actionEvent.getActionCommand());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

`((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getLabel()`

This will give you the label of the button clicked. You need to type cast the `Source` to `Button` like `(Button)actionEvent.getSource()`

Your code should be

```
private void dodajCrko(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           
    jlStatus.setText(jlStatus.getText() + 
    ((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getLabel());
}
```

As @Anto said, You should use `actionEvent.getActionCommand()` if you use any toggle buttons because the command string would identify the intended action.

Comment: And how can I determine if the pressed item is JMenuItem or JButton?

Comment: you can typecast (uppercast) to `JComponent` and then do an `instanceof` test with `JButton` and `JMenuItem`.

Comment: thank you, but the getActionCommand is avoiding the `instanceof` which is, I think, a lot better

Comment: Great! I was fast to answer but, forgot that one ;) Glad it helped! You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion i find this works better.

```
private JButton button1;
```

Then use this.

```
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Button 1 was presseed");
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps, Luke.

Comment: I have about 20 buttons and I have to identify which one of them is pressed, so what @Anto wrote is working perfectly fine